# How to connect NVIDIA CUDA PCI-E graphic card over USB?

Tags: cuda, usb, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I would like to run some CUDA calculations, but I have only simple notebook without NVIDIA.

Is there any USB adapter that allows to connect NVIDIA graphic card to my notebook?

That would be great if there is such a device, that I connect my NVIDIA card, plug it into my computer, run calculation, and disconnect from laptop until calculations are finished.

Comment: i am actually looking forward for an answer, but unfortunately i don't think you will get it here...because its not the place for asking such question....

Comment: I don't believe there is such a thing.  But there are a number of ways to get free access to a system with GPUs installed.  If you are a university student, check with your university.  There is also something called [GPU Test Drive](http://www.nvidia.com/object/gpu-test-drive.html).  Also, if you have access to a desktop system, for less than $50 (probably what you would spend on a usb adapter if there were one) you can install an NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: Amazon also has a service you can get a free trial for http://aws.amazon.com/hpc-applications/

Comment: If you are techy you could also attempt to construct an eGPU. Some manufacturers did make some of these devices but they seem laptop specific. Looks like a challenge to make one yourself though. Example: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/2560pinternal.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

USB is very-very slow compared to the internal bus to the graphics card in a PC, so the speed of the GPU for calculations would be wasted by the long time to copy the data there and back.

USB is alos message based, it doesn't allow your computer to see the GPU card memory (or the other way around) so you would effectively need another computer on the GPU end to unwrap things.

There is a new high speed connector called Thunderbolt which is (essentially) the PCIe bus inside your computer connected to a socket. This would allow an external device (like a GPU) to act like it was directly connected to the bus. But it's only on a few expensive models  today and not many devices exist for it (yet).

Amazon do now offer GPUs on their cloud service, but this might be a bit expensive for just learnign / playing with.

Comment: he wasnt asking for a gaming rig, speed between laptop cpu and computer gpu might not be the issue then.